# Problems with CSS3 animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my first question and I'm so happy for this

I created a page with fullpage.js [Roadmap](https://boneos.org/roadmap.html)

I would create an animation with CSS3, so I saw an easy [tutorial](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/css-animation/)

I followed instructions and I pasted code to roadmap.html
Animation works well, but I don't know why there are 14 rockets with blue brackground. You can see "glitch" [Here](https://boneos.org/roadmap.html)

Any error with js ? Is it a problem with css?

```html
<style>#outerspace{position:relative;height:400px;background:#0c0440 url('http://www.the-art-of-web.com/images/rocket.gif');color:#fff;}div.rocket{position:absolute;bottom:10px;left:20px;-webkit-transition:3s ease-in;-moz-transition:3s ease-in;-o-transition:3s ease-in;transition:3s ease-in;}div.rocket div{width:92px;height:215px;background:url('http://www.the-art-of-web.com/images/rocket.gif') no-repeat;-webkit-transition:2s ease-in-out;-moz-transition:2s ease-in-out;-o-transition:2s ease-in-out;transition:2s ease-in-out;}#outerspace:hover div.rocket{-webkit-transform:translate(0px,-5400px);-moz-transform:translate(0px,-5400px);-o-transform:translate(0px,-5400px);-ms-transform:translate(0px,-5400px);transform:translate(0px,-5400px);}</style>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: *"t I don't know why there are 14 rockets with blue brackground"* .. how should we know, there are neither rockets, blue or otherwise colored, nor code showing any rockets being created, in your question ?

Comment: There are lots of 404 errors - the links do not appear to be valid - e.g. `https://boneos.org/vendors/scrolloverflow.js`.  I think this is a problem with relative URLs.

Comment: To see the thing on the website itself, you have to go to Developer Tools and delete the `<div>` elements that cover the real deal where the problem is.

Comment: How about you insert some line wraps in your code? How readable is it currently, what do you think?

Comment: *"This is my first question and I'm so happy for this"* -- That's so adorable. :3 Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of the first thing in your CSS where you said for `#outerspace`:

```
background: #0c0440 url('http://www.the-art-of-web.com/images/rocket.gif');
```

The url part should not be there at all. If you wrote `no-repeat`, there would still be 1 rocket that shouldn't be there, so to sum it up:

Take out `url('http://www.the-art-of-web.com/images/rocket.gif')` from the `background` of `#outerspace`.

The code should be:

```
background: #0c0440;
```

Here is your reassurance:

```css
#outerspace{position:relative;height:400px;background:#0c0440;color:#fff;}div.rocket{position:absolute;bottom:10px;left:20px;-webkit-transition:3s ease-in;-moz-transition:3s ease-in;-o-transition:3s ease-in;transition:3s ease-in;}div.rocket div{width:92px;height:215px;background:url('http://www.the-art-of-web.com/images/rocket.gif') no-repeat;-webkit-transition:2s ease-in-out;-moz-transition:2s ease-in-out;-o-transition:2s ease-in-out;transition:2s ease-in-out;}#outerspace:hover div.rocket{-webkit-transform:translate(0px,-5400px);-moz-transform:translate(0px,-5400px);-o-transform:translate(0px,-5400px);-ms-transform:translate(0px,-5400px);transform:translate(0px,-5400px);}
```

```html
<div id="outerspace">
<div class="rocket">
<div></div>
BoneOS
</div>#outerspace
</div>
```